# neo4j query for path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following nodes in my graph:

```
Car

Trash

CarToTrash
 [:has_input]-(Car)
 [:has_output]-(Trash)

RecycleTrash
 [:has_input]-(Trash)
 [:has_output]-(Car)
```

I'm trying to find a query which will give me all shortest paths between the two types, i.e.

(Car)-[has_input]-(CarToTrash)-[has_output]-(Trash)-[has_input]-(RecycleTrash)-[has_output]-(Car)

The length of the path can vary though. It can have more nodes like XToY with an has_input and has_output relation. I'd like to find the shortest path between any two types I might add to the graph. CarToTrash and RecycleTrash represents function and the relation has_input and has_output is the input type and return type of the function. Basically what I have is a graph of types and functions, and I'd like to see check if there is a path of functions between any two arbitrary types in the graph.

I've tried with the following query which works somewhat, but it would find paths which does not follow the pattern has_input, has_output if those existed. Also I tried finding the way from Car back to Car which I was unable to do, I could only find Car to Trash, I might manage without though if it's not possible to query this kind of loops.

```
MATCH car, trash WHERE car.uid='Car' AND trash.uid='trash'
WITH car, trash MATCH p = allShortestPaths(car-[*..15]-trash) return p;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want structure in your shortest-path path segments, I believe that this algo is not usable for you.

I should probably device your own traversal algo, and use the Java API to do it, based on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html, which gives you even more flexibility than current Cypher here.

Comment: Thanks. Will this functionality eventually be available in Cypher?